# Class Rectangle, existe uma classe circular?

Tags: java

Eu sei que Class Rectangle é em forma retangular para colisão de objetos, existe uma classe Circular para esse fim?

Comment: Qual é o contexto? Dê mais detalhes, só com isso não dá nem pra ter ideia do que está falando.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, existe. É a [Ellipse2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html)

Você pode usar os seus métodos `contains` e `intersects` para verificar colisões.

É claro que uma elipse não é necessariamente um círculo; mas uma elipse com altura e largura com a mesma medida, é um círculo :-)

Importante notar que a classe `Ellipse2D` em si é abstrata, de modo que você deve usar suas filhas `Ellipse2D.Float` ou `Ellipse2D.Double`, dependendo da precisão desejada. Por exemplo:

```
Ellipse2D elipse = new Ellipse2D.Float(x ,y, w, h);
```

Para mudar as coordenadas da elipse depois de instanciá-la, use o método `setFrame`. Por exemplo:

```
elipse.setFrame(x, y, w, h);
```

Comment: você poderia me dar um exemplo de implementação, pois estou usando O `Rectangle` onde se passa o `x ,y, width e height` pelo construtor nesse  eu não sei onde passo eles?

Comment: @Rodolfo Você pode passar no construtor também. Resposta editada.

Comment: Porque eu não consigo fazer isso `this.elipse.x =  this.x` ? já no `Rectangle` funcionava

Comment: @Rodolfo Ao alterar a elipse, você precisa setar todas as suas coordenadas ao mesmo tempo. Resposta editada.